# Android: Display image from file in highest resolution

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I have quite the annoying problem. I'm building an app where one can share photos. On the SurfaceView where you take the actual photo, the resolution is great. However, when I retrieve that image and display it in a ListView using Picasso, the resolution goes to crap. The pixelation is real. Is there anything that I'm doing horrendously wrong to cause this? The first code snippet below is where I actually save the photo, and the one below that is my getItemView() method in my adapter for the listview. Thanks in advance.

Note that the "photo" variable you see in my code is a Parse subclass I've created to make it easier working with data associated with each photo. I think you can safely ignore it.

EDIT:

SurfaceView of Camera:
Note that I attempt to set the camera parameters to the highest quality allowed. Unfortunately, when I LOG size.width and size.height, I can only get around 176x144. Is there a way to get a higher resolution for supported camera sizes itself?

```
                     camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                     Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                     parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 70);

                     parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
                     List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
                     Size size = sizes.get(Integer.valueOf((sizes.size()-1))); 
                     parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
                     camera.setParameters(parameters);
                     camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

                     List<Size> sizes2 = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                     Size size2 = sizes.get(0);

                     parameters.setPreviewSize(size2.width, size2.height);
                     camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                     camera.startPreview();
```

Saving the photo:

```
    // Freeze camera 
    camera.stopPreview();

    // Resize photo 
    Bitmap mealImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    Bitmap mealImageScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mealImage, 640, 640, false);

    // Override Android default landscape orientation and save portrait
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotatedScaledMealImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mealImageScaled, 0,
            0, mealImageScaled.getWidth(), mealImageScaled.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    rotatedScaledMealImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

    byte[] scaledData = bos.toByteArray();

    // Save the scaled image to Parse with the date and time as its file name.
    DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH MM SS");
    photoFile = new ParseFile(currentTime.toString(fmt), scaledData);
    photo.setPhotoFile(photoFile);
```

Displaying it:

```
    final ParseImageView photoView = holder.photoView;
    ParseFile photoFile = photo.getParseFile("photo");

    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(photoFile.getUrl())
            .into(photoView, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

            });
```

Comment: have you checked the result with file explorer?

Comment: Yeah I want to make an answer for that but I think I just want to confirm it to you first, because I don't see any problem when you are trying to display it using picasso

Comment: @nayoso You've helped me pinpoint the problem. Is the problem my phone's camera itself, or the camera I've set up?

Comment: OK for one more confirmation can you show me the your camera setup code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the Picasso

It because this line of code

```
parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 70);
```

and this

```
List<Size> sizes2 = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Size size2 = sizes.get(0);
```

When you setup the camera you already turned down the quality to the 70% (because based on the Android Documentation the range of jpeq-quality is between 0-100)

And then you also need to check is the size of the camera is correct or not, because you are making assumption with that code

you can try this code to get the best preview size with your preffered width and height

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters){
     Camera.Size bestSize = null;
     List<Camera.Size> sizeList = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

     bestSize = sizeList.get(0);

     for(int i = 1; i < sizeList.size(); i++){
      if((sizeList.get(i).width * sizeList.get(i).height) >
        (bestSize.width * bestSize.height)){
       bestSize = sizeList.get(i);
      }
     }

     return bestSize;
    }
```

I hope this answer will help you, if you have another question about my answer you can try to ask me in the comment :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. For some reason, setting the camera to a higher resolution prevents the ParseObject "photo" from saving. When it does and I can look at the file itself, I'll report back.